# google colabでimport mecabがエラーになる

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

google colabでmecab-python3をpipインストールした後、import mecabするとエラーになります。
1.mecab本体をインストール:成功

```
!apt-get install mecab mecab-ipadic-utf8 libmecab-dev swig
```

2.mecab-python3をインストール:最新ver0.8.2は失敗するので、ver0.8.0指定で成功。

```
!pip install mecab-python3==0.8.0
```

3.importするとエラー

```
import mecab
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-71af23e59d14> in <module>()
----> 1 import mecab

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mecab'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

google colabのnotebookはこちらです。
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Bm81uSoJQOyERAi0wDvrvZ-A-ex2-cbf

大変恐縮ではございますが、皆様の温かいご指導ご鞭撻を期待しております。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　リンク下さっている colab へアクセスするには権限が必要なようです。「You need permission」と表示されました。

Comment: 不慣れで申し訳ございません。下でコメントさせて頂きましたが、colabのランタイム開放、再実行で現在問題が解決しております。また問題発生しましたらお世話になります。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

問題点1

macabのインポートは、小文字ではなくパスカル形式の文字になります。

```
import MeCab
```

問題点2

`mecab-python3`のver0.8のパッケージに問題があったようです。

・ https://github.com/SamuraiT/mecab-python3/issues/11

PyPIの方は、ver0.7になっています（戻した可能性が大）。 https://pypi.org/project/mecab-python3/
swigのインストールは不要で、従来の方法でインストールできると思います。

```
!apt-get install libmecab-dev mecab mecab-ipadic-utf8
!pip install mecab-python3
```

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。今しがたGoogle colabのランタイムを初期化した後にインストールすると、正常にmecab-python3インストール完了することを確認しました。
お騒がせしました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

ライブラリ名の大文字小文字が異なっています。`import mecab` ではなく `import MeCab` としてみてください。

参考: https://pypi.org/project/mecab-python3/ からサンプルプログラムを引用します。

```
import MeCab
mecab = MeCab.Tagger ("-Ochasen")
print(mecab.parse("pythonが大好きです"))
```

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。大文字小文字気をつけます。下でコメントさせて頂きましたが、一旦colabのランタイム開放、再試行でうまくいくことを確認しました。ありがとうございます。